# How can I change annotation title on Apple Maps Route

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, maps, apple-maps

I've created a route from A to B with MKMapItem, but I can't change the title of the annotation on the map. My code:

```
CLLocation *locationRestaurante = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[[listaRestaurante objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue] longitude:[[[listaRestaurante objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]];

        MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:locationRestaurante.coordinate addressDictionary:nil];

        MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];

        NSDictionary *options = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};

        [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];
```

it opens everything just fine... But there's only one problem: The I can't change this annotation name:

[image: unknown location]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapItem.name = @"Place name";
```

[MKMapItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html)